# Redirect to edit page automatically if record exists

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, redirect

I want to create a new record if it not exist. Otherwise, redirect to edit page automatically.

In case the record exists (e.g: `@sale` is not `nil`). However, I got error message:

> app/views/sales/_form.html.erb where line #1 raised:
>
> First argument in form cannot contain nil or be empty

Please show place where I had mistake.

sales_controller.rb

```
  def new
    @sale = Sale.find_on_today
    if @sale.nil?
      @sale = Sale.new
    else
      redirect_to edit_sale_path(@sale)
    end
  end

  def edit
  end

  # POST /sales
  def create
    Kpi.transaction do
      @sale = Sale.new(sale_params)
      @sale.user_id = current_user.id
      respond_to do |format|
        if @sale.save
          format.html { redirect_to sales_path, notice: 'Sale was successfully created.' }
        else
          format.html { render :new }
        end
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /sales/1
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @sale.update(sale_params)
        format.html { redirect_to sales_path, notice: 'Sale was successfully updated.' }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
      end
    end
  end

  private
  def sale_params
    params.require(:sale).permit(:sale_money, :no_of_items)
  end
```

_form.html.erb

```
<%= form_for @sale do |f| %>
  <label for="sale_money"><%= t('.sale_money_label')%></label>
  <%= f.text_field :sale_money, class: "form-control" %>

  <label for="no_of_items"><%= t('.no_of_items_label')%></label>
  <%= f.text_field :sale_amount, class: "form-control" %>

  <%= f.submit t('.btn_submit'), class: 'btn btn-primary' %>
<% end %>
```

UPDATE: Based on fylooi's answer, I forget redirect is a new request, so `@sale` is `nil`. I change method `new`, `edit` and `update` in controller, it is working

sales_controller.rb

```
def new
    @sale = Sale.find_on_today
    if @sale.nil?
        @sale = Sale.new
    else
        redirect_to edit_sale_path(@sale.id)
    end
end

def edit
    @sale = Sale.find(params[:id])
end

def update
    @sale = Sale.find(params[:id])
    respond_to do |format|
      if @sale.update(kpi_params)
        format.html { redirect_to kpis_path, notice: 'Sale was successfully updated.' }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
      end
    end
end
```

edit.html.erb

```
<%= render partial: 'form' %>
```

Comment: From which `view page` you are calling that partial?

Comment: edit.html.erb call `<%= render partial: 'form'  %>`. Should I pass whole instance variable to partial (`<%= render partial: 'form', collection: @sale %>`? How can I use the variable in partial?

Comment: Is @sale = Sale.find_on_today returns only single record?

Comment: yes @sale is single record

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `redirect` is a fresh request to Rails. You need to set `@sale` again in the `edit` action as it is not persisted from `update`.

Alternatively, you can render the `edit` view directly from `update` if the update fails. That will preserve the instance variables from `update`.